# Is $M_0(\mathbb F)$ a valid construct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Or, is there a $\text{dim}\ 0$ matrix ring? I assume you can define $M_0(\mathbb F) := \{[]\}$ and $\mathbf I_0 := []$, but I couldn't find any confirmation on this.

Comment: What properties/function would you want it to have? What I mean is, sure, we can "define" whatever we like, but if we have _goals_ for the thing we've described, our definition/construction may not serve those purposes.

Comment: @paul garrett The question's first form was, "What is the lowest rank identity matrix?". I'd like to know if there is any concensus on $\text{dim}\ 0$ matrices, because if there is not, trivial group & identity is not really a good candidate for it.

Comment: * For the lowest dim identity, sorry about that

Comment: Sure, why not.   We have vector space $V$ of dimension $0$.  We have the space $L(V,V)$ of linear transformations from $V$ to itself.  When we choose a basis for $V$ (empty set) the matrix representing the unique element of $L(V,V)$ will be the unique $0 \times 0$ matrix.

Comment: This arises categorically in the following way: fix a field $k$, and imagine the category where objects are nonnegative integers, and a morphism from $n$ to $m$ is an $m \times n$ matrix with entries in $k$. (This category is equivalent to the category of finite-dimensional $k$-vector spaces). Then $0$ is a zero object, so there is a unique morphism from any $n$ to $0$ (the $0 \times n$ matrix), and a unique morphism from $0$ to any $n$ (the $n \times 0$ matrix). The unique morphism from $0$ to itself is the $0 \times 0$ matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your definition is right (and useful). See [Carl de Boor, *An empty exercise*](ftp://ftp.cs.wisc.edu/Approx/empty.pdf).

Comment: I had a somewhat similar motivation to define them as I did. It is great to see how and why your intuition makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

There is no generally accepted consensus on what a "dimension $0$ matrix" would be. Here is what I would say:

I prefer linear transformation instead of matrices.

For $n\geq 1$, the matrix algebra $M_n(\mathbb{F})$ is isomorphic to the algebra of linear operators on $\mathbb{F}^n$, so we might just say that  $M_0(\mathbb{F})$ is the algebra of linear operators on $\mathbb{F}^0$.

But what is $\mathbb{F}^0$?

Well, for $n,m\geq 1$, we have natural isomorphisms $\mathbb{F}^n\times\mathbb{F}^m\to\mathbb{F}^{n+m}$, so we might just try to extend this to allow the same type of isomorphism for $n$ or $m=0$. That is, we should have $\mathbb{F}^n\times\mathbb{F}^0\cong\mathbb{F}^n$. Taking the dimensions on both sides, we obtain $n+\dim(\mathbb{F}^0)=n$, i.e., $\dim(\mathbb{F}^0)=0$. So a natural definition is $\mathbb{F}^0=\left\{0\right\}$, the null space.

This definition behaves quite well with respect to the natural isomorphisms: $\mathbb{F}^n\times\mathbb{F}$ is naturally isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}^{n+m}$ for all $n,m\geq 0$.

Ok, so $M_0(\mathbb{F})$ should be the algebra of linear operators on $\mathbb{F}^0=\left\{0\right\}$. This is just the null algebra: $M_0(\mathbb{F})=\left\{0\right\}$. This is the definition I would adopt, although I make no claims on how useful it is.